# Can a dynamic object be a UIImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uikit-dynamics

I have a `UIDynamicAnimator` with behaviour: `UIPushBehaviour`. I know the `UIView` objects can become a dynamic object with `initWithReferenceView`. But is it possible for a dynamic object to be a `UIImageView`. And if so, how?

(I have read the apple developer documents and I can't really grasp the `UIDynamicAnimator` concepts, so forgive me if this is stupid)

Comment: Image views _are_ `UIView` objects and conform to `UIDynamicItem` protocol just like `UIView` does. So just use the `UIImageView` where you would have otherwise put your `UIView`. It just works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing ever "becomes a dynamic object." That's not the way to think about it. A dynamic animator has behaviors. Behaviors have items. A view can be an item. So that means that `UIDynamicAnimator` can animate a `UIImageView`. The view has no idea that it's being animated. It just gets `setCenter:` called on it repeatedly (and as @Rob notes below, also `setTransform:` and `bounds`). There's no difference here between an image view and any other kind of view.

The key to understand is that UIKit Dynamics is completely backwards. In `UIView` animations and in Core Animation, the view is pretty intimately involved in being animated. You can ask a view for its animations, add and remove them, etc. But UIKit Dynamics is glued on and works entirely from outside the view. You cannot ask a view if it is being managed by UIKit Dynamics. You can only ask UIKit Dynamics what views it is messing with (and you can't always easily ask that).

In my experience, UIKit Dynamics can work reasonably if your animations are extremely simple. But if things are complex at all, you probably need to do it by hand with Core Animation (or SpriteKit, depending on your need). There is also very little documentation for it. Oh, and the various behaviors have very inconsistent APIs. It's not my favorite framework in Cocoa...

If you want to see some examples of this, you may want to pull down the sample code from iOS 7:PTL ([iosptl.com](http://iosptl.com)) [Chapter 19](https://github.com/iosptl/ios7ptl/blob/master/ch19-dynamics/Dynamics/Dynamics/ViewController.m). It includes putting push animators onto views.